# Looking for a bibliography style that implements specific formatting requirements

Tags: bibtex

I was wandering if any of you know the name of the references' style in the following format:

FLEISHMAN J., 1983, ed., The Future of the Postal Service, New York, Praeger.

PELTZMAN S., 1976, 'Toward a more general theory of regulation', Journal of Law and Economics, 211-40.

Or, know how to do it in latex/bibtex?

I used to use apalike style:

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document} ... 
\bibliographystyle{apalike} 
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

I was trying with other names of references but I didn't find the format which is required.

Comment: Related, a list of standard and common BibTeX styles: [Choosing a BibTeX Style](http://www.reed.edu/cis/help/latex/bibtexstyles.html)

Comment: Two aspects of your preferred layout are quite uncommon: (i) placing "ed." *after* the year, and (ii) showing the `pages` field but neither the `volume` nor the `number` fields for entries of type `@article`. Doubtful that there are ready-made bst files that use these stylistic settings. Do look into using the [makebst utility](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) to create a custom-built bst file.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create you own bibstyle for bibtex/natbib with makebst if you want it to look exactly like that.

Or, if you have time and some patience, you could switch to biblatex. It takes some time getting used to it, but in the long run it saves a lot of trouble because you can easily change nearly every detail on the basis of an existing style without recreating any one particular style completely.